# Form inside php tags causes error 403, outside of it - does not

Tags: php, html, post, xampp, echo

Why does such code cause error 403 on form submit?

```
<?php
echo '<form name=\"pass\" action=\"upload\" method=\"post\">';
echo '<input name=\"wordno1\" type=\"text\" />';
echo ' <input name=\"wordno2\" type=\"text\" />';
echo ' <input value="pass" type="submit" />';
echo '</form>'; ?>
```

but such code does not?

```
<form name="passer" action="upload" method="post">
<input name="wordno1" type="text" />
<input name="wordno2" type="text" />
<input value="pass it" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I read somewhere that it may be a security issue that disallows echo in POST method.
Is it true?
If so, is there any way I could change this setting?

btw. I'm using XAMPP

---

Marked as duplicate but the problem was kind of different. In this question I didn't ask about quotation marks but about  inside php echo causing error 403.
Just the solution somehow came down to a basic issue of proper quotating.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: Your first version has `name="pass"`, the second has `name="passer"`. Although the name of the form isn't used for much, so I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: 403 error comes from the webserver, not PHP. Make sure that the `action` URL is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `action="upload.php"`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, those backslashes were the case here, thank you

Comment: no need for upload.php because I use RewriteRule in .htaccess

Comment: The backslashes shouldn't cause a problem, they're just redundant.

Comment: Oh, actually they are a problem. Backslash isn't ignored inside single quotes.

Comment: The only characters you can escape inside single quotes are backslash and single quote. In all other cases, the backslash is treated literally.

Comment: thanks, didn't know what is really the case here, I rarely use php